# compareTo() Java Quick Question

Tags: java, class, methods, if-statement, compareto

I have this method in my code

```
public boolean has(AnyType x){

        for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
            if(items[i] == x)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

and I want to rewrite the if statement to use the compareTo() method, and according to what I remember it should be something like this:

```
if(items[i].compareTo(x) == 0)
```

But that is giving me an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong??

Comment: So obviously items[i] is null. Now find out why this is so.

Comment: yeah I have a counter for keeping the size of the array, after I remove some items there are some nulls since I am working with arrays, so I had to change the items.length in the if statement to counter

Comment: More about NullPointer Exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception

Comment: You should be using equals(), not compareTo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NullPointer Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. Check with your `items[i]` values. One of the value must be a null, so that's why the compiler is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

```
if(items[i].compareTo(x) == 0)
```

When you do this, you are trying to compare a null value with `x`, which indeed throws a `NullPointerException`.

Do check for the **`not-a-null-value`** test. Try this,

```
public boolean has(AnyType x){

      for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i] != null && items[i] ==x)
                   return true;
         return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it, I did have some null values indeed. I just changed the items.length to the counter which keeps the next empty value in the array.

Answer (score 3):

One of your items[] is null.
Check if the elements are properly set to non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

One of your items is null, you can validate it before attempting to call `compareTo`.

You can also use the enhanced for loop:

```
public boolean has(AnyType x){
    for( AnyType n : items ) {
        if( ( n == null && n == x )  || 
            ( n != null && n.compareTo( x ) == 0  ) ) { 
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```